# View listener for passing from a view in android

Tags: android

i have a view , i make an on Touch Listener for it

suppose we touch a point out of the view range , and move our finger on screen , i try to find a way to execute the listener when the finger overfly or pass from the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
View.setOnHoverListener(View.OnHoverListener l);
```

Only works if you are working with API over 14, though. If not, in your `onTouchListener`, use:

```
switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
case ACTION_MOVE:
    your code
break;
case ACTION_UP:
    your code
break;
```